# Why does scrapy return an error saying "'LoginSpider' object has no attribute 'logged_in'"?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to scrape data from a website I must log into first. For this reason, I have been trying to use LoginSpider as outlined here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin

My script is very similar to the example one given at the above link. However, when I try to run my script from the command line, lately, I have been getting a long error message of which the last line is: "builtins.AttributeError: 'LoginSpider' object has no attribute 'logged_in'" I looked around other forums for other answers to this question but couldn't find any that seemed to touch on this specific issue.

What follows is the entirety of my spider.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
def authentication_failed(response):
# TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if it failed
# or False if it succeeded.
    pass
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wine'
    start_urls=['https://www.jancisrobinson.com/#login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'cathy@enolytics.com', 'password': 'purple'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )
    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:
            self.logger.error("Login succeeded!")
            item = SampleItem()
            item["quote"] = response.css(".text").extract()
            item["author"] = response.css(".author").extract()
            return item
    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.jancisrobinson.com/#login",
                                   formdata={'user': 'john', 'pass': 'secret'},
                                   callback=self.logged_in)]
```

As per request, here is the full command line traceback produced the last time I ran this spider:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/myspider.py", line 24, in start_requests
    callback=self.logged_in)]
builtins.AttributeError: 'LoginSpider' object has no attribute 'logged_in'

2020-06-12 10:02:24 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
  File "/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Documents/Scripting/my_project/spiders/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/myspider.py", line 24, in start_requests
    callback=self.logged_in)]
AttributeError: 'LoginSpider' object has no attribute 'logged_in'
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because you haven't defined the method `self.logged_in` inside your spider class. You are referencing this method here:

```py
return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.jancisrobinson.com/#login",
                                   formdata={'user': 'john', 'pass': 'secret'},
                                   callback=self.logged_in)
```

What this does is that after scrapy does this request, the `self.logged_in` method will be executed. You need to define this method:

```py
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wine'
    start_urls=['https://www.jancisrobinson.com/#login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'cathy@enolytics.com', 'password': 'purple'},
            callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:
            self.logger.error("Login succeeded!")
            item = SampleItem()
            item["quote"] = response.css(".text").extract()
            item["author"] = response.css(".author").extract()
            return item

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.jancisrobinson.com/#login",
                                   formdata={'user': 'john', 'pass': 'secret'},
                                   callback=self.logged_in)]

    def logged_in(self,reponse):
        # do something here
        pass
```

Or ...

You need to change `self.logged_in` by one of your existing methods. Please let me know if this helps, and if not, don't hesitate to ask any question I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, EnriqueBet. It appears you're just saying I need to add this part to the bottom of the spider: def logged_in(self,reponse):
        # do something here
        pass (I wish I could hit return to get to a new line here but if I do that it just saves the post instead, oh well...) I have added the above code to the bottom of my spider and it no longer gives the error message I described in this post originally.

Comment: I am glad this helped you, let me know if you have any questions